# First Timer using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Ok so I got a project using recursion and it's a little hard to comprehend but I need some help. I am trying to take user input and pass it into the method `f` and then it uses recursion on the line `f(n)=2(2n+1)*f(n−1)/n+2`. Then it should print out what `f(n)` equals, but it's giving me an error while trying to set up the line in the method `f`.

A sample run of the project would be like `10` is `n` and the `f(n) = 58786`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Recursive
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an integer for n");

        long n = input.nextLong();

        System.out.println("f(n) = " + f(n));
    }

    public static long f(long n)
    {
        if (n <= 0) return (n=1);
        if (n > 0) return (2(2n+1)*f(n−1) n+2 );
    }
}
```

Comment: And the error is....?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if (n > 0) return (2(2n+1)*f(n−1) n+2 );
```

with

```
return 2 * (2 * n + 1) * f(n - 1) / (n + 2);
```

In java, `2n` is not equal to `2*n`. You need to explicitly put that multiplication asterisk sign. Same with brackets.

Full method is:-

```
public static long f(long n) {
    if (n <= 0) return 1;
    return 2 * (2 * n + 1) * f(n - 1) / (n + 2);
}
```

It prints `58786` for the input `10`.

Comment: Ok now I feel dumb because I actually knew that. But Thank You so so much!!